# Binary Search O(log2(n)) Change of Base

Tags: performance, search, binary-search, organization

In a binary search, I know that its complexity runs with log2(n). The search utilises the fact that the list is ordered, so we can assume that each item in an array has a 'tag' (its index) as additional information to reduce run-time. Is there any way to add additional 'tags' to reduce its complexity even further? To phrase it differently, is there another level of organization we can implement to search items more effectively?

Comment: Aha perhaps misuse of language. I just meant it uses it, I guess abuse is a little aggressive of a word.

Comment: To use your own words, yes, there is a way to 'tag' much more smartly. And you get O(1) performance on an average. It's called hashing!

Comment: Would you please remove the 'binary-tree' tag? It's not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

if your search algorithm is based on compare, and the list is ordered, the log2(n) is the lower bound. However, there is some space-time trade off algorithm or data structure which also could be used for searching. The most common one is [HashTable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is applicable for your case, but if you're dealing with simple associative logic (i.e., you don't have a key/value distinction, only keys), and your clients already have access to keys and are simply trying to figure out if an element belongs to the container, then there's an extremely simple and fast solution here that often eludes many when looking for the data structure to do the job.

Simply store one or more backpointers (or back references depending on the language) to the container inside the key. Now you no longer search the container to see if an key belongs to it. You search the key itself, among its backpointers, to see if it belongs to a container.

This will often outperform even the fastest hash table implementations provided that your keys do not belong to too many containers at once. If they belong to only one container at a time, then it's a blazing fast constant-time check to simply see if the back pointer points to the container you're interested in.

This is a more intrusive solution than a container which is completely decoupled from your key representation, but it's hard to beat its speed for set logic (finding if something belongs to a set, finding set intersections, unions, differences) if your needs match the criteria: that is, you are working with simple associative logic and your keys do not belong in too many of such aggregates at once.

Comment: Is there a term for this kind of algorithm? I googled a couple of key words you mentioned but I am a little unsure of how this method would work and would like to learn more.

Comment: It's not really sophisticated enough to call an algorithm/data structure, as it's merely a back pointer or a flag to indicate when an element is inside the container, and if back pointer(s), which. If you also store an index in the key, then you can find out not only which container an element belongs to, but where, in O(1).

Comment: It's like how do you find out what parent node is associated with a child node in a tree structure? Well, you could search the whole entire tree using preorder/inorder/postorder tree traversal, or you can exchange space for time and just store a back pointer to the parent node in the child node. Then you can immediately know what the parent node is given any child. If you do these types of "given a child, what's the parent?" queries a lot, then the back pointer can help tremendously over constantly searching data structures.

Comment: Basically you can always use an associative structure to externally associate data to an element, like a hash map. Given some Key type `K`, you can _associate_ more data to it than it normally has externally. But that external association means you pay the price of a search to fetch that data associated with `K`. Or you can always just store that data _inside_ `K`, and take the associative middleman out of the picture. If you're doing set logic, you can store what set(s) to which `K` belongs to turn what would be a search into a simple retrieval of a field value.